# Wagtail: Updating Django 1.10.8 -> 1.11 - ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldPanel'

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm currently working on upgrade my Wagtail sites and got stuck.

Wagtail: 1.13.4
Django: 1.10.8

Site works fine in Django 1.10.8 but throws an `ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldPanel'` in 1.11 when i attempt to `python manage.py runserver`.

I don't have any migrations to do, and i've checked as i've stepped my Wagtail versions up from 1.5 through this point.

I have a custom user model, in an app called members and they're declared in my project settings like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',
    'overextends',
    'dashboard',
    'lineage',
    'gunicorn',
    'wagtail.wagtailforms',
    'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
    'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
    'wagtail.wagtailsites',
    'wagtail.wagtailusers',
    'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
    'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
    'wagtail.wagtailimages',
    'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
    'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
    'wagtail.wagtailcore',
    'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',

    'members',

    'modelcluster',
    'compressor',
    'taggit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
#lots of extra stuff here.. editted for brevity...
WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "mySite"
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'members.MyUser'
```

Here's the trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\maeda\Sites\la-print\home\models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import (FieldPanel,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\edit_handlers.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .forms import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wagtail\wagtailadmin\forms.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, PasswordResetForm
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 22, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 189, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 203, in get_model
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\maeda\Sites\la-print\members\models.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import (FieldPanel,
ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldPanel'
```

Comment: See https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4515

Comment: Thanks Selcuk. This has done much for my sanity. I'll be watching this git issue with great interest.